# Guess current date/time on remote server

Tags: hacking, fingerprint

I want to know the current date/time of a remote server.
I do not have any access on this server.

This server expose OpenSSH (port 22) and apache2 (port 80)

Is there a fingerprint technique that can reveal current timestamp on this 2 services ?

Thanks

Comment: `curl -s --head http://serverfault.com | grep '^Date: '`

Comment: Or `wget --method=HEAD -S -q http://serverfault.com 2>&1 | grep '^ *Date: '`

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP protocol has the `Date` header ([RFC 7231, 7.1.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.2)) *for the date and time at which the message was originated*. That's typically the time on the server in UTC.

> When a Date header field is generated, the sender SHOULD generate its
> field value as the best available approximation of the date and time
> of message generation.  In theory, the date ought to represent the
> moment just before the payload is generated.  In practice, the date
> can be generated at any time during message origination.

This is not really fingerprinting nor hacking, but a feature of the protocol. Also, every reasonably configured server should be configured to automatically update and keep correct time using NTP. The information you are looking for could only be somewhat useful if it wasn't, and in very specific conditions as discussed e.g. in [Is exposing the server time a security risk?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187316/is-exposing-the-server-time-a-security-risk)